# On iOS and Cocoa Touch, is there a control for a slide out panel for iPad / iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

This might be a common UI, that when we tap on an `i` icon, that a sliding panel slide out from the bottom or from the right of the screen, a bit like how Angry Birds slide out the panel from the left.

Does Cocoa Touch already have something like that built in or another control that can be easily converted for such use?  Otherwise, is there some alternatives that may fit this purpose and is recommended in general on iPad / iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's just a matter of showing a view (some panel) when a button (your icon) is tapped, using an animation to slide it in from the side. See: [SubView slide in animation, iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343915/subview-slide-in-animation-iphone)

Comment: yes, just looking for something that is more pre-built, so that no need to re-implement it every time.  And if it is a pre-built control, maybe it can have nice 3D graphics such as a groove line at its border that has a bit of a shadow

Answer (score 1):

I had a pretty specific use case to address and ViewDeck was the perfect fit.  The menu mimics the menu you'll see in Facebook or Path.  It's animates smoothly and has great gesture interactions:

https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

Answer (score 0):

I've been using

[MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

quite successfully for side drawer functionality in the iPad app I've been building for a national healthcare company

Dealing with Cocoapods/config is often a bit tricky with 3rd party components, and one also needs to bear in mind whether the component will continue to be supported as new iOS versions come out, but generally this component works well as of iOS8 and I'd recommend it.